# Viewing ST_MULTIPOLYGON data from ArcSDE DB2 

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, db2

We have inherited some tables that were created with ArcGIS/ArcSDE, and the data in these is still being used by our main web application to perform some spatial lookups.  The queries are pretty simple, we just pass in some x/y coords and the query returns a code uniquely identifying the shape that the coords exist in.

The majority of the mapping solution has now been decommissioned as we are no longer providing live maps, and thus we no longer have the Arc toolset.  The basic lookups remain however, and the customer wants to provide us with a new shapefile for import.  We used to use the tools to check that the new shapefile fit in with the existing ones visually, and to assign the unique code to the shape.  Without the tools I am unsure how to proceed.

There are three tables, each of which is associated with a different lookup, and each table has a column that looks like:

```
Column     Type      Type
name       schema    name               Length   Scale Nulls
---------- --------- ------------------ -------- ----- ------
SHAPE      DB2GSE    ST_MULTIPOLYGON           0     0 Yes
```

along with some other columns.  Can anyone recommend any free tools we can use to view this data visually?  Is it even possible?

Sorry if this comes off as very basic or n00bish, I'm a Java & Web developer and have no real experience with GIS solutions.  If you need any other info please let me know.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that your ST Geometry Database in DB2 is registeredt with SDE? If you can open Command Prompt on the server and type "sdeservice -o list" this will tell us if an SDE service is running.

Comment: No, we don't have any of the SDE applications any more, just the data in these three tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you can access an IBM DB2 + Spatial Extensions installation, then you'll perhaps be able to integrate your data and then convert it to shapefiles :

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/opt/csbp4178.htm